# How to populate spinner from mySql database

Tags: android, mysql

How do i populate this,I have 2 Spinners in my app and one is for Province and other is for City, when i select Gauteng in province spinner i want my second spinner to show Johannesburg,Pretoria,Centurion and If i select KZN in province i want my second spinner to show Maritsburg and Durban.

im using mySql database and i have Province table and City table.
Here is My Province table(idprovince,provincename)

```
1   Gauteng 
2   Free-State 
3   Limpopo 
4   Northen-Cape 
5   North-West 
6   Western-Cape 
7   Eastern-Cape 
8   Kwa-Zulu-Natal 
9   Mpumalanga
```

and Here is my city table(idcity,cityname,province_idprovince)

```
1  Johannesburg    1 
2   pretoria    1 
3   Centurion   1 
4   Bloemfontein    2 
5   Welkom  2 
6   Polokwane   3 
7   Phalaborwa  3 
8   Potgiersrus 3 
9   Tzaneen 3 
10  Kimberley   4 
11  Upington    4 
12  Mafikeng    5 
13  Klerksdorp  5 
14  Mmabatho    5 
15  Potchefstroom   5 
16  Brits   5 
17  Cape-Town   6 
18  Stellenbosch    6 
19  George  6 
20  Saldhana-Bay    6 
21  Bisho   7 
22  Port-Elizabeth  7 
23  East-London 7 
24  Pietermaritzburg    8 
25  Durban  8 
26  Ulundi  8 
27  Richards-Bay    8 
28  Newcastle   8 
29  Nelspruit   9 
30  Witbank 9 
31  Middleburg  9 
32  Ermelo  9
```

i will appriciate your help.

Comment: This is a place where you ask people to help you with problems that you may have with your coding. It is not a place where you request work to be done for you. Please see the type of questions one should ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I'm confused. Did u mean you use `sqlite` or you use `mysql` over server-client architecture

Comment: your question is quite unclear what have you tried and what do you really want??

Comment: post the code man not the db ?

Comment: @kaluwila i do not know where to start thats why im asking for help

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at loading your spinners by following some tutorials such as this one http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?start=2

Answer (score 0):

ok then you should take a look at some tutorials to get the basic of spinners 
after doing that

1 step: get the data from db and set it to first spinner using adapter

2 step: on the first spinner's OnItemSelected event you have to set second adapter as well (get data from db according to selected item and set it to second spinner using adapter)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example . here i got the details from sever using SAX parsing .here District_districtname and district_districtid are arraylists where i am storing the details from server

```
Spinner sp1, sp2;
ArrayList<String> loc = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> mov = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, district_districtname);
    // apply the Adapter:
    sp1.setAdapter(ad);
    sp1.clearFocus();

    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            int pos = sp1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            selecteddistrict = district_districtname.get(pos);

            loc.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < district_districtname.size(); i++) {

                if (district_districtname.get(i).equals(selecteddistrict)) {

                    districtid = district_districtid.get(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < locality_localityname.size(); j++) {

                        if (locality_districtid.get(j).equals(districtid)) {

                            loc.add(locality_localityname.get(j));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);

    ArrayAdapter<String> ad2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, loc);
    // apply the Adapter:
    sp2.setAdapter(ad2);

    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
```

}